# How can i turn this If/if else statement into a non if statement

Tags: reactjs

so i have these if statements, and i need to turn them into something that doesn't use switch cases/if else statements, this is a react app.

```
{data.map((val, key) => {
            if (val.kg) {
              return (
                <div className="cardproductlist" key={key}>
                  <div className="valuescontainercheckbox pt-4 ml-3">
                    <input
                      class="delete-checkbox"
                      type="checkbox"
                      value={val.sku}
                      id={val.sku}
                      onChange={handleCheck}
                    />
                  </div>
                  <div className="valuescontainer">
                    <span> {val.name}</span>
                  </div>
                  <div className="valuescontainer">
                    <span> {val.price}$</span>
                  </div>
                  <div className="valuescontainer">
                    <span>{val.sku}</span>
                  </div>
                  <div className="valuescontainer">
                    <span className="pb-5">
                      <span>Weight: {val.kg} KG</span>
                    </span>
                  </div>
                </div>
              );
            } else if (val.mb) {
              return (
                <div className="cardproductlist" key={key}>
                  <div className="valuescontainercheckbox pt-4 ml-3">
                    <input
                      class="delete-checkbox"
                      type="checkbox"
                      value={val.sku}
                      id={val.sku}
                      onChange={handleCheck}
                    />
                  </div>
                  <div className="valuescontainer">
                    <span> {val.name}</span>
                  </div>
                  <div className="valuescontainer">
                    <span> {val.price}$</span>
                  </div>
                  <div className="valuescontainer">
                    <span>{val.sku}</span>
                  </div>
                  <div className="valuescontainer">
                    <span className="pb-5">
                      <span>Size: {val.mb} MB</span>
                    </span>
                  </div>
                </div>
              );
            } else if (val.length) {
              return (
                <div className="cardproductlist" key={key}>
                  <div className="valuescontainercheckbox pt-4 ml-3">
                    <input
                      class="delete-checkbox"
                      type="checkbox"
                      value={val.sku}
                      id={val.sku}
                      onChange={handleCheck}
                    />
                  </div>
                  <div className="valuescontainer">
                    <span> {val.name}</span>
                  </div>
                  <div className="valuescontainer">
                    <span> {val.price}$</span>
                  </div>
                  <div className="valuescontainer">
                    <span>{val.sku}</span>
                  </div>
                  <div className="valuescontainer">
                    <span className="pb-5">
                      <span>
                        Dimensions: {val.length}x{val.width}x{val.height}
                      </span>
                    </span>
                  </div>
                </div>
              );
            } else {
              return (
                <div className="cardproductlist" key={key}>
                  <div className="valuescontainercheckbox pt-4 ml-3">
                    <input
                      class="delete-checkbox"
                      type="checkbox"
                      value={val.sku}
                      id={val.sku}
                      onChange={handleCheck}
                    />
                  </div>
                  <div className="valuescontainer">
                    <span> {val.name}</span>
                  </div>
                  <div className="valuescontainer">
                    <span> {val.price}$</span>
                  </div>
                  <div className="valuescontainer pb-5">
                    <span>{val.sku}</span>
                  </div>
                </div>
              );
            }
          })}
        </div>
```

Comment: Hi, Could you please let me know what is the main purpose that you want to achieve?

Comment: Looking at the four `cardproductlist` divs shows a lot of duplication, with only the text content within the "valuescontainer" divs differing. So I'd look at reducing this down to one block (that is iterated over `data.map`) and using a function that accepts data and returns the value within the div: `<span>{selectMiscData(data)}</span>`.

Comment: Hello, the main goal is that i cannot use if/else statements to render object types, but i haven't found another method yet to display the dynamic type of data for the products like "Dimensions,Size, Weight" based on the data type from the database, like every product has a sku,name,price and a dynamic input with different data like those mentioned above, and when the products are rendered the title should be chosen based on the data type if that makes sense

Answer (score 0):

I don't know is it best practice for conditional rendering but enums can be used for it.

```
const elementStates = {
  kg: <YourKgElement />,
  mb: <YourMbElement />,
  default: <DefaultElement />
};

function YourElement({state}) {
  return <div>{elementStates[state]}</div>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i have found a way to do it without using a huge if else block,this works for now,

````
                    {val.kg ? <div>Weight: {val.kg} KG</div> : ''}
                    {val.mb ? <div>Size: {val.mb} MB</div> : ''}
                    {val.length ? (
                      <div>
                        Dimensions: {val.length}x{val.height}x{val.width}
                      </div>
                    ) : ''}
                  </span>```
````